# Estimating position of peak in noisy sequence data

Tags: time-series, probability, python

I have a sequence of data with peaks in it; ideally, they represent a point I have to track in space. The point movement is rather smooth, but there are two problems:

- peaks change sign relatively to their surroundings (sometimes they are "below", other times they are "above"),
- there is noise, and sometimes signals are barely visible.

Luckily, I know that point position will not change drastically most of the times, therefore I could use knowledge I am confident into to estimate point position when I am not sure about it. Also, begin and end data will coincide (it's a loop).

Take a look [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA5qR.jpg) to understand what is the (unlabeled) data I am working with (I had to skip some frames to upload it, movement is smoother in reality).

Knowing that in some points the downhill point is what I want to track, how can I estimate its position when peaks are barely visible and/or inverted?

I thought about using PGMs, but I have no idea on how to model this problem with continuous distributions and how to do inference with it. Another tool that I thought could be useful is Kalman Filter, but, again, I am not sure about to model it.